# Find the first/last n words of a string with a maximum of 20 characters using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to find any number of ***words*** at the beginning or end of a string with a maximum of 20 characters.

This is what I have right now:

```
s1 = "Hello,    World! This is a reallly long string"
match = re.search(r"^(\b.{0,20}\b)", s1)
print(f"'{match.group(0)}'") # 'Hello, World! This '
```

My problem is the extra space that it adds at the end. I believe this is because \b matches either the beginning or the end of the string but I'm not sure what to do about it.

I run into the same issue if I try to do the same with the end of the string but with a leading space instead:

```
s1 = "Hello,    World! This is a reallly long string"
match = re.search(r"(\b.{0,20}\b)$", s1)
print(f"'{match.group(0)}'") # ' reallly long string'
```

I know I can just use rstrip and lstrip to get rid of the leading/trailing whitespace but I was just wondering if there's a way to do it with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `r"^(.{0,19}\S\b|)"` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN3w4v/1)), `\S` ensuring to have a non space character on the bound. You need to decrease the number of previous characters to 19 and use `|` with empty string to match 0 characters if needed:

```
import re
s1 = "Hello,    World! This is a reallly long string"
match = re.search(r"^(.{0,19}\S\b|)", s1)
print(f"'{match.group(0)}'", len(match.group(0)))
```

Output:

```
'Hello,    World' 15
```

For the end of string `r"(|\b\S.{0,19})$"` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cBfQyl/1)):

```
import re
s1 = "Hello,    World! This is a reallly long string"
match = re.search(r"(|\b\S.{0,19})$", s1)
print(f"'{match.group(0)}'", len(match.group(0)))
```

output:

```
'reallly long string' 19
```

###### why `(...|)`?

to enable zeros characters, the below example would fail with `^(.{0,19}\S\b)`

```
import re
s1 = "X"*21
match = re.search(r"^(.{0,19}\S\b|)$", s1)
print(f"'{match.group(0)}'", len(match.group(0)))
```

output:

```
'' 0
```

Comment: @anubhava yes, they could be removed (I had copied OP's code), but they don't hurt either ;)

Comment: A tiny bit less efficient, not inefficient. This should add at most 1 extra check. So O(1). But you're right best it to remove it, I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^\S.{0,18}\S\b|\b\S.{0,18}\S$
```

`\S` (not a whitespace) at start and end guarantees that your matches start and with with a non-whitespace character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EvCNKF/1)

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/xKRxh0)

**code:**

```
import re

s = "Hello,    World! This is a reallly long string"

print(re.findall(r'^\S.{0,18}\S\b|\b\S.{0,18}\S$', s))
# ['Hello,    World', 'reallly long string']
```